# Teamcity multiple tags in cucumberoptions

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, teamcity

When i run test cases in intellij, its working as expected with two tag @sit_env and @MOBILE.

```
-Dcucumber.options="--tags @sit_env --tags @MOBILE"
```

But when i try to execute through teamcity, its running all test cases and ignoring tags which i m passing. I tried in multiple ways but couldnt able to succeed.

Below all 3 are running all test cases and ignoring my tags which i m passing

```
clean test --rerun-tasks "-Dcucumber.options= --tags @sit_env --tags @MOBILE"
clean test --rerun-tasks -Dcucumber.options="--tags @"sit_env" --tags @"MOBILE""
clean test --rerun-tasks -Dcucumber.options="--tags @sit_env --tags @MOBILE"
```

Below all 3 failing with Unknown command-line option '--tags'

```
clean test --rerun-tasks -Dcucumber.options= --tags @sit_env --tags @MOBILE 
clean test --rerun-tasks -Dcucumber.options= --tags "@sit_env" --tags "@MOBILE"
clean test --rerun-tasks -Dcucumber.options="--tags @"sit_env" "--tags @"MOBILE"
```

Please help.

Comment: try to pass `-Dcucumber.options='--tags @sit_env --tags @MOBILE'`

Comment: we didnt have System.getProperty in gradle. It was the issue.